# Google colab no muestra markdown

Tags: python, ipython

Si import markdown de la clase Ipython del a siguiente forma y creo un objeto de tipo Markdown

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
display(Markdown("**hello**"))
```

me regresa esto:

```
<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>
```

pero lo que espero ver seria esto:
**Hello**

Necesito crear celdas de markdown automaticamente, he probado hacerlo de forma local con jupyter, pero en google colab no.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do:

```py
In [903]: from IPython.display import display                                                                                               

In [904]: markdown_string = '''\
     ...: hello world 
     ...: '''                                                                                                                               

In [905]: display({'text/plain': markdown_string,'text/markdown': markdown_string},raw=True)
hello world
```

as in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377801/jupyter-notebook-vs-jupyter-console-display-of-markdown-and-latex-html-etc

Comment: Hola, traduce tu respuesta, recuerda que el idioma oficial del sitio es el español, revisa [answer]. saludos.

Comment: hey uds (menos @jack) vamos... eliminen la respuesta (y haganla pasar por suya, adelante) o siganle bajandole la puntuacion; ese es el deporte favorito de todos uds aqui, en especial a respuestas acertadas. esto resulto ser tan o mas letrina que twitter.

Comment: hey... tambien seria bueno q se buscaran/inventaran un Python en español... o necesitan tambien q les traduzca "from" o "import" o mejor "markdown"?. hey... sugieranle tambien a @jack q use un ejemplo mas apropiado a sus intereses, q escriba "hola" en vez de "hello", cierto?